# Flutter app: How to replace or not replace /assets files in new version update?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Suppose I have the following two files in the "assets" directory of my Flutter app:

(1) assets/database.db

(2) assets/settings.json

Whenever I release a new version, I want to achieve the following two things.

When a user updates to the new version of the app:

(1) assets/database.db: This file will be **COMPLETELY REPLACED**.

(2) assets/settings.json: This file will **NOT BE REPLACED**. I want to keep it as it is **without any change**.

How can I achieve the above two things in every new version of my app?